# Add users in azure AD group using terraform by fetching the user details from CSV file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform

I am following this documents [Manage Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Users and Groups](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/azure-ad) and the same repo mentioned in the same page to add  user in Azure AD group.

I don't need a resource function to create users because users are already created by another team. We just need to create the groups and add the members into it.

I am able to add the user to group by creating a tfvars file with members email address

terraform.tfvars

```
dev-team = [
  "a@example.com",
  "b@example.com"
]
```

groups.tf

```
data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each            = toset(var.dev-team)
  user_principal_name = each.key
}

resource "azuread_group" "api-jnk-cld-ops" {
  display_name = "api-jnk-cld-ops"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "member" {
  for_each         = toset(var.dev-team)
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.api-jnk-cld-ops.id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].id
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "dev-team" {
  type = list(string)
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is, users should be listed in csv file instead of giving in tfvars. The same way as official documents mentioned [Manage Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Users and Groups](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/azure-ad) only different is i don't want to create user.

Fetch the user and check which department user belongs to and add the user to the correct group this is what I am trying to do..

Error: New issue if i have duplicate UPN that is using in another group.

> Two different items produced the key
> "user1@example.com" in this 'for' expression. If
> duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to
> enable grouping by key.

```
AzureGroup  Surname UserPrincipalName   UserSamAccountName  GroupName   ObjectClass DistinguishedName   GivenName   Enabled AzureUserPrincipalName  AzureUserId
api-jnk-cld-ops user1   user1@example.com   abcd    api-jnk-cld-ops user        user1   TRUE    user1@test.onmicrosoft.com  fad08bd2-3fa471403656
api-jnk-ai-ops  user2   user2@example.com   defg    api-jnk-ai-ops  user        user2   TRUE    user2@test.onmicrosoft.com  5f2d00eb-bfc6-67219cec3bb7
api-jnk-bd-ops  user1   user1@example.com   abcd    api-jnk-bd-ops  user        user1   TRUE    user1@test.onmicrosoft.com  fad08bd2-3fa471403656
```

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "member" {
  
  for_each = { for user in local.users : user.AzureUserPrincipalName => user if user.AzureGroup == "api-jnk-cld-ops" }
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.api-jnk-cld-ops.id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].id
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I am trying to achieve is, users should be listed in csv file
> instead of giving in tfvars. The same way as official documents
> mentioned Manage Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Users and Groups
> only different is i don't want to create user.

You can use the below code for your requirement:

```
provider "azuread" {}
locals {
  users = csvdecode(file("C:/user.csv"))
}
data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for user in local.users : user.UPN => user }
  user_principal_name = each.value.UPN
}

resource "azuread_group" "dev-team" {
  display_name = "inx-dev"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "member" {
  for_each = { for user in local.users : user.UPN => user }
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.dev-team.id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].id
}
```

**CSV FILE:**

[image]

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

**Update for the below error :**

[image]

If you are using Duplicates then you will have to convert the list to map by doing indexing, so you can use the for the loops like below :

```
data "azuread_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for i , user in local.users : i => user }
  user_principal_name = each.value.AzureUserPrincipalName
}

resource "azuread_group" "dev-team" {
  display_name = "inx-dev"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "member" {
  for_each = { for i,user in local.users : i => user  if user.AzureGroup == "api-jnk-cld-ops" }
  group_object_id  = azuread_group.dev-team.id
  member_object_id = data.azuread_user.user[each.key].id
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works perfect!! Thanks. If we are mentioning the same UPN in another group then I am getting error......

If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...)
after the value expression to enable grouping by key.

Comment: I edited my question with the issue I am facing with duplicate UPN. Any help will be much appreciated @AnsumanBal-MT

Comment: @hashimvayalar,checking ...

Comment: @hashimvayalar, added the solution for the error , please find it in update section of the answer.

Comment: works perfect!!!!!Thanks a lot...

Comment: Glad to be of help @hashimvayalar:)) !!